# Choropleth heat map missing some area

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, heatmap, choropleth

I'm trying to create a heatmap for countries. I've created a custom geojson, which is working fine, by it's own.

Unfortunately, when I link to the dataframe where the amount are displayed, only part of the heat map are rendered, excluding some areas.
Why is that?

Thanks a lot

[data and code available here](https://github.com/vincenzojrs/test)
[image: my gdf]
[image: the heatmap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed one important parameter:  **featureidkey**  This is the join between the geometry and data frame (**location**)

Have also simplified your aggregate to removed need for `reset_index()`

#### full code

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

gdf = gpd.read_file(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincenzojrs/test/main/map-2.geojson"
)

sellers = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincenzojrs/test/main/sellers.csv"
)

sellersxcity = sellers.groupby(["id_ac"], as_index=False).agg({"num_ord_sell": "sum"})

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    sellersxcity,
    geojson=gdf,
    featureidkey="properties.ID_1",
    locations="id_ac",
    color="num_ord_sell",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    zoom=3,
    center={"lat": 40.4999, "lon": -3.673},
    labels={"num_ord_sell": "Count for Orders"},
)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})
```

Comment: Give this man a medal! Thanks sir!